# Remove specific string from string input in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an string from title, and i want to remove specific character/string from this.
Title is show with `bloginfo('sitename')`.

I try to made something like that:

```
<?php
   $title = preg_replace('/'. preg_quote('SRL', '/') . '$/', '', bloginfo('sitename'));
   print $title;
?>
```

...but don't work.

The `title input` is: `SOMETHING SRL`, and i want to show just `"SOMETHING"`.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why don't you use `str_replace`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `preg_replace()` use `str_replace()` like below:-

```
echo trim(str_replace('SRL','',$title)); // first replace `SRL` and then remove extra spaces
```

so the code will be:-

```
<?php
   $title = trim(str_replace('SRL','',$title));
   print $title;
?>
```

Output:-  https://3v4l.org/NTrFJ

Answer (score 3):

Use str_replace() Function

```
str_replace("SRL","",$title);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $title = "SOMETHING SRL";
 $title = trim(str_replace("SRL","",$title));
```

Use this code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace()` with `trim()`.

The `str_replace()` function replaces some characters with some other characters in a string.

```
str_replace(find,replace,string,count)
```

**Note:** String Parameter is Required. Specifies the string to be searched and count is optional

**Use like this**

```
 $stringReplace = "Hello World";
 $stringReplace = trim(str_replace("world","Programmer","Hello world!"));
```

**Output**

```
Hello Programmer
```